# Как сделать волны с частичным наложением?

Tags: html, css, svg

Как создать подобное `SVG`, тут как я понял работает наложение оттенков, подобное этому:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div>
  <svg viewbox="0 0 100 25">
  <path fill="#9EAFFD" opacity="0.5" d="M0 30 V15 Q30 3 60 15 V30z"/>
  <path fill="#9EAFFD" d="M0 30 V12 Q30 17 55 12 T100 11 V30z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавить `opacity: 0.5` для второго `path`:

```html
<div>
  <svg viewbox="0 0 100 25">
    <g fill="#9EAFFD">
      <path opacity="0.5" d="M0 30 V15 Q30 3 100 15 V30z"/>
      <path opacity="0.5" d="M0 30 V12 Q30 17 55 12 T100 11 V30z"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```